# Nomenclature Stokes Theorem

Tags: stokes-theorem

I have a profound understanding of the **classical Stokes theorem** (aka Curl theorem). However, I am a little confused, how the theorem is written on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem)
$$
\iint_\Sigma (\nabla \times \mathbf{F}) \cdot \mathrm{d}^2 \mathbf{\Sigma}  =  \oint_{\partial\Sigma} \mathbf{F} \cdot 
\mathrm{d}\mathbf{\Gamma}.
$$
Could someone explain the deeper meaning of the square on the left side?

Comment: That $d^{\color{red}{2}}\Sigma$ only indicates that it is a surface integral which should be clear from the context. Write $dS$ if you like that better.

Comment: Seems a bit strange. Math should not depend on context.

Comment: Moreover, $\Sigma$ is already defined as surface, see the link.

Comment: Notation isn't math. It helps to express mathematifal statements in more or less convenient ways that depend on what people are used to. There is never a notation that explains itself. Either the author does that or it is clear from context.

Comment: Wise words. However, it is neither described on the page nor it is clear from context. As I already said, in the picture $\Sigma$ is defined as surface. For me, it is simply wrong or missleading.

Comment: Then you may want to discuss that with those who wrote that Wikipedia article.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your reply.

Comment: Personally I prefer [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4685250/949989) notation because I want to see the vector normal to the surface.

Comment: D'accord. Looks more reasonable.

Comment: But then came [Elie Cartan](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4183216/949989) and found something even better. :)

Comment: I like Elie, especially for $v \times w = \left(\star(v^\flat \wedge w^\flat )\right)^\sharp$.

Comment: He was an absolute genius, and the gem Hopeful Whitepiller found in that link is marvellous. I cannot stop laughing about that Absinthe.